# Notification Center iOS7 bug?

Tags: ios, notifications

Before submitting to Apple I'd like to know if anyone else has this problem on an iOS7 device

The images is in Dutch, but the visual should be clear.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the bug is being shown… Are you currently pressing the screen for that row to remain in that place or has it 'stuck' there?

Comment: Holding it and dragging it around on that page.

Comment: Indeed, I am able to reproduce this, but I'm wondering if this is even a bug — it's dragging to where you've placed your finger: what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Not go above "Inclusief" as that's the top of the 'table' if I can name it that way. Why would you drag it outside an area to place it nowhere? ;p

Comment: Hmm, I suppose…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I am able to reproduce this bug in all of the UITableViews with reordering. Whilst I'm not convinced it's a bug, it is indeed reproducible in all views I've encountered.

Comment: Alright, I just rolled my eyes when finding out somehow. Silly stuff.. "Do a barrelroll" in Google..